# Radius Request Sending Error

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, radius, freeradius, radius-protocol

My informations are here.

```
username : user
password : testing123
secret   : testing123
```

I am using virtual machine and I want to create radius server on this, then I want to send Request on my Windows OS.

I try the following command (VM):

```
radtest user testing123 127.0.0.1 0 testing123  (Successful Result)
```

Then I try to sending request on "NTRadPing Radius Server Test Tool" I am getting following msg.(Window)

```
Ready to process requests.
Ignoring request to authentication address * port 1812 from unknown client 192.168.*.* port 60062

Ready to process requests.
Ignoring request to authentication address * port 1812 from unknown client 192.168.*.* port 60062

Ready to process requests.
Ignoring request to authentication address * port 1812 from unknown client 192.168.*.* port 60062
Ready to process requests.
```

Could you please help me?

Thank You
Can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every device that communicates with the radius server must have an entry in `raddb/clients.conf`. Typically this is something like:

```
client <name> {
    ipaddr = <ipaddr>
    secret = <shared secret>
}
```

You need to add an entry in clients.conf that matches the machine you're running ntradping from (and restart the server).